# Contact form doesn't work on Submit

Tags: javascript, php

I am not sure why my contact doesn't work. It doesn't submit & send data to my email address.
Check it on Live- http://www.arif-khan.net/project/chuck/ContactUs.html

Check out HTML Code-

```
<form id="contact-form" action="sendmail.php" method="POST" >                       
                    <div class="success">Contact form submitted!<br>
                        <strong>We will be in touch soon.</strong>
                    </div>                      
                    <fieldset>
                        <label class="name">
                            <input name="name" type="text" value="Name:">
                            <span class="error">*This is not a valid name.</span> 
                            <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="email">
                            <input name="email" type="email" value="Email:">
                            <span class="error">*This is not a valid email address.</span> 
                            <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="phone">
                            <input name="contact" type="tel" value="Phone:">
                            <span class="error">*This is not a valid phone number.</span> 
                            <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="message">
                            <textarea name="message">Message:</textarea>
                            <span class="error">*The message is too short.</span> 
                            <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="form_buttons">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn-1" value="submit" style="border:0px;">
                            <!--a href="#" id="submit" class="btn-1 submit" data-type="submit">submit</a-->
                            <a href="#" class="btn-1" data-type="reset">Clear</a>
                            <input id="contact-form" type="hidden" name="contact-form" type="submit"/>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

Check out PHP code-

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
$to = "arifkpi@gmail.com";

$content = 'Customer Request From Pennant Staffing';

$body_message = '---------- Customer Details ---------- '."\r\n\r\n";
$body_message .= 'Name: '. $name."\r\n\r\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: ' . $email ."\r\n\r\n";
$body_message .= 'Contact: ' . $contact."\r\n\r\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: ' . $message."\r\n\r\n";

$headers = "From:$name<$email> \r\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n"; 
mail($to, $content, $body_message, $headers);
?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
window.location = 'ContactUs.html';
</script>
```

Comment: CAN YOU PLEASE ALSO POST YOUR HTML CODE?

Comment: what is not working? mail is not sending or something else?

Comment: do you have an smtp server and all the right stuff configured in php to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From:$name<$email> \r\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";
mail($to, $content, $body_message, $headers);
```

for checking mails on localhost u can use "Test Mail Server Tool"

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into the php.ini file you use for this project and search for

```
[mail function]
```

and set up the variables for the SMTP server.